# Is there an alternative way of implementing inheritance of static methods in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm very new with dart.

I have some `enums` like `HairType`, some Classes that simulates `enums` with a `random()` method like: `SkinColors` and `ShortHair`.

The class `SkinColors` have also a `values` property to simulate a `List` so I can use both: `SkinColors.colors` or `SkinColors.values`.

Everything was working fine:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

void main(){
  print(SkinColors.tanned);
  print(SkinColors.values);
  print(SkinColors.colors);
  print(SkinColors.random());
  print(ShortHair.dreads01);
  print(ShortHair.values);
  print(ShortHair.random());
}

class SkinColors {
  // This class is not meant to be instantiated or extended; this constructor
  // prevents instantiation and extension.
  // ignore: unused_element
  SkinColors._();

  static const Color tanned = Color(0xFFFD9841);
  static const Color pale = Color(0xFFFFDBB4);
  static const Color brown = Color(0xFFD08B5B);

  static const List<Color> colors = <Color>[
    tanned,
    pale,
    brown,
  ];

  static List<Color> get values => colors;

  static random() => values[Random().nextInt(values.length)];
}

enum HairType {
  bigHair,
  bob,
  bun,
  dreads01,
  dreads02,
  frizzle,
}


class ShortHair {
  // This class is not meant to be instantiated or extended; this constructor
  // prevents instantiation and extension.
  // ignore: unused_element
  ShortHair._();

  static const HairType dreads01 = HairType.dreads01;
  static const HairType dreads02 = HairType.dreads02;
  static const HairType frizzle = HairType.frizzle;

  static const List<HairType> values = <HairType>[
    dreads01,
    dreads02,
    frizzle,
  ];

  static random() => values[Random().nextInt(values.length)];
}
```

Then, I decided to move redundant code (I have more similar classes in my real code) `random()` and `get values` to a common place. So, I created two abstract class, `BaseEnum` with the `random()` method and `ColorsEnum` with `get values`:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

void main(){
  print(SkinColors.tanned);
  print(SkinColors.values);
  print(SkinColors.colors);
  print(SkinColors.random());
  print(ShortHair.dreads01);
  print(ShortHair.values);
  print(ShortHair.random());
}

abstract class BaseEnum {
  static const values = [];

  static random() => values[Random().nextInt(values.length)];
}

abstract class ColorsEnum implements BaseEnum {
  static const List<Color> colors = <Color>[];

  static List<Color> get values => colors;
}

class SkinColors implements ColorsEnum {
  // This class is not meant to be instantiated or extended; this constructor
  // prevents instantiation and extension.
  // ignore: unused_element
  SkinColors._();

  static const Color tanned = Color(0xFFFD9841);
  static const Color pale = Color(0xFFFFDBB4);
  static const Color brown = Color(0xFFD08B5B);

  static const List<Color> colors = <Color>[
    tanned,
    pale,
    brown,
  ];
}

enum HairType {
  bigHair,
  bob,
  bun,
  dreads01,
  dreads02,
  frizzle,
}


class ShortHair {
  // This class is not meant to be instantiated or extended; this constructor
  // prevents instantiation and extension.
  // ignore: unused_element
  ShortHair._();

  static const HairType dreads01 = HairType.dreads01;
  static const HairType dreads02 = HairType.dreads02;
  static const HairType frizzle = HairType.frizzle;

  static const List<HairType> values = <HairType>[
    dreads01,
    dreads02,
    frizzle,
  ];
}
```

Something is wrong with this implementation because I'm getting this errors:

> line 6 • The getter 'values' isn't defined for the type 'SkinColors'. (`SkinColors.values`)
> line 8 • The method 'random' isn't defined for the type 'SkinColors'. (`SkinColors.random()`)
> line 11 • The method 'random' isn't defined for the type 'ShortHair'. (`ShortHair.random()`)

It's supposed that both method should be inherited by classes `SkinColors` and `ShortHair`.

**Edit:** @julemand101 give me some light in the comments. So, now that I know that I can't inherit static methods, my new question is: **How can I give the same `random()` method to all my clases without repeating the same code in every class?**

**Answer:** It seems that there's no way to do what I want to do in Dart. But @KirillBubochkin give in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66509062/4599564) a nice way of doing something similar with `extensions`

Comment: There are multiple problems but I think the major problem is your are expecting static fields and methods to be carried over when you extend a class which they don't. This also means that you cannot really have a interface for `static` fields/methods.

Comment: Thank you @julemand101, I come from PHP and I didn't know about not inheritance of static fields/methods. I updated my question: There's another way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go with an extension on a `List`:

```dart
extension RandomElement<T> on List<T> {
  T random() => this[Random().nextInt(length)];
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```dart
SkinColors.values.random();
ShortHair.values.random();
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a very interesting approach. Could you please explain to me why if I do the same with `enums`:
Something like: `extension RandomEnumElement on HairType {
  HairType random() => HairType.values[Random().nextInt(HairType.values.length)];
}` I got the error: **The method 'random' isn't defined for the type 'HairType'**?

Comment: Forgot it! I was using `HairType.random()` instead of `HairType.values.random()`. Could you, please, update your answer to include the same extension for the HairType enum? Mine is working but isn't probably the most effective way of writing it :)

Comment: @JuanAntonioTubío did you add `import 'dart:math'` ? Because the code you provided should work otherwise.

Comment: Sorry for the mess in the commentary section. I fix it and commented about in the second one because I didn't know that I could delete my comments. Thank you very much.

PS: I asked you for one example of making the same extension for HairType, but your extension on List is also working on Enums, so I don't need to add another extension.